# Django request to find previous referrer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm passing the request to the template page.In django template how to pass the  last page from which the new page was initialised.Instead of history.go(-1) i need to use this

```
 {{request.http referer}} ??

 <input type="button" value="Back" /> //onlcick how to call the referrer
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

That piece of information is in the [`META`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) attribute of the `HttpRequest`, and it's the `HTTP_REFERER` (sic) key, so I believe you should be able to access it in the template as:

```
{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}
```

Works in the shell:

```
>>> from django.template import *
>>> t = Template("{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}")
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> req = HttpRequest()
>>> req.META
{}
>>> req.META['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'google.com'
>>> c = Context({'request': req})
>>> t.render(c)
u'google.com'
```

Comment: Also u r saying that <input type="button" value="Back" onlick="window.location='{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}'"/>  would work..

Answer (score 26):

Rajeev, this is what I do:

```
 <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">Referring Page</a>
```

Comment: friend, I want to implement it on the item selection page(which is a bootstrap modal). when the user wants to add a product to his wishlist, I want a link to the products page and a back button to the wishlist page ( which is a form in that BS modal). I used it, but it takes me back to the page that contains the modal, Can I go back to the page with that modal open and have the same values in the input boxes which is in it?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`
With this you won't get an error if doesn't exist, you will get None instead

Answer (score 2):

With 2 lines of code below, I could get **referer** in overridden `get_queryset()` in **Django Admin**:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        
    def get_queryset(self, request):

        print(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) # Here
        print(request.headers['Referer']) # Here
        
        return super().get_queryset(request)
```

Output on console:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/store/person/ # request.headers['Referer']
http://localhost:8000/admin/store/person/ # request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```