# Django: how to show different html elements depending on where visitor came from?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. On my template, I want to show a message if a visitor came from a certain page. For example, if user is from www.abcdef.com then the page would show the message:

Hi there!

If user is from any other url, the message would not be shown. I've been messing around with {{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}} but I'm still lost. Thanks in advance!

Comment: {{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }} should work. What error do you get? What does request.META.HTTP_REFERER output to your templates (try printing it out in a <p> tag). Check you're passing a RequestContext object to your render_to_response function

Answer (score 0):

If you're using links to navigate from page to page you could hardcode it in your links, so that:

```
 <a href='/main/welcome?from={{path|urlencode}}'>
```

And in the page that you are redirected to, use

```
 page=request.GET.get('from', None)
```

To get where the user came from, and set up your logic from there.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the HTTP Referrer in your view and pass it with your context, you don't nesscarily have to pass the refereer you could pass in a Boolean context variable, or both - which I would recommend  - this will allow you to do keep a cleaner template, and would allow you to tailor messages more appropriately .

**Getting the Referrer:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406377/django-request-to-find-previous-referrer

After you have sent the variables through your context variable try checking against them in your template. I added refer_approved_source which you can check against a list and set in your view it doesn't have to have that name just used for illustration purposes.

```
{% if refer_approved_source == 'source' %}
  It looks like you are from {{refer}}
{% endif %
```