# 'dict' object has no attribute 'HTTP_REFERER'

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I've been trying to find the previous url following this answer:

[Django request to find previous referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406377/django-request-to-find-previous-referrer)

So, in my .py I did:

```
print request.META
print request.META.HTTP_REFERER
print request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

*request.META* returns:

```
{'RUN_MAIN': 'true', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/contact/', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/user', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim',....
```

So, I can see HTTP_REFERER is there, but when trying to access it either way I get the error:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>
'dict' object has no attribute 'HTTP_REFERER'
```

How can I access it?

Comment: Your second line is throwing this, right?

Comment: Your third line is correct. The second is not, thus the exception. And as the second raised an exception, the third is never executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Comment: Note that this has a different behavior. It will return `None` if the header is not in `META`, instead of raising a `KeyError` exception. Depending on what you do with the value, it's a useful shorthand for catching the exceptin or it might let a miss go unnoticed.

Answer (score 4):

`request.META` is a dictionary. Your code fails when you do

```
print request.META.HTTP_REFERER
```

Because you are trying to access `HTTP_REFERER` as attribute, but you should access it as item with

```
print request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

If you are not sure that you have this item in `request.META` you can use `get` method as other answerers suggested

```
print request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
```

This will output `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` if `HTTP_REFERER` is in `request.META` otherwise it will print `''` which you provided as second argument to `get`. `''` will be default value.

Comment: @DidinaDeen point is you shouldn't do `print request.META.HTTP_REFERER`

Comment: Well, I meant I tried both ways and I would get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

try: `request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "")`