# Back button to a related object

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I'm building an app where I can add recipes and add ingredients to those recipes. On view **recipe_details** I have a button to **add_new_ingredient**. When I'm on new_ingredient_form I want to have **back button** to get back to the details of recipe. I'm trying to pass recipe's **pk** but it doesn't work. How am I able to pass recipe's pk to be able to back to previous view?

models.py

```
class Recipe(Timestamp):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    preparation = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Ingredient(Timestamp):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class RecipeView(generic.DetailView):

    model = Recipe
    context_object_name = 'recipe'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ingredients_list'] = Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=self.object.pk)        
        return context
        

class AddIngredientView(generic.edit.CreateView):

    model = Ingredient
    fields = [
        'name',
        'amount',
        'unit'
    ]
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'recipes/add_ingredient.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.recipe = self.recipe
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):

        if 'add_another' in self.request.POST:
            url = reverse_lazy('recipes:add_ingredient', kwargs={'pk': self.object.recipe_id})

        else:
            url = reverse_lazy('recipes:recipe', kwargs={'pk': self.object.recipe_id})

        return url
```

add_ingredient.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add_another">Save and add another</button>
    <a href="{% url 'recipes:recipe' recipe.pk %}", class="btn btn-primary", role="button">Back</a>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the previous page by adding `{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}` to the href property of the button.

[Django request to find previous referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406377/django-request-to-find-previous-referrer)